# Join three tables on two columns with blanks where they don't match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join three tables on two different columns, with the caveat that I want there to be blanks when certain columns don't match up. The tables hold data on math and English test, so I am joining two test tables based on a common test column with a student table through ID column that they all have in common.

As you will see from the images below, in some cases, the same test contains both math and English, so this appears in both tables, but in other cases, separate tests are written.

The three tables are:

[image: Student Table]

[image: English Test Table]

[image: Math Test Table]

As you can see, the MEG10 test is shared between both English and Math, as they are written together and are in the same test. This is where I am getting tripped up, as I want the join to display all the results when the tests appear in both English and math. When the tests are separate, however, I want it to have blanks in the English or Math columns with "stuff" (because there isn't actually information in those supposed-to-be-blank columns), respectively. Essentially, when I join them, I want the resultant table to be the one shown below.

[image]

The code that I am using to join them is:

```
SELECT 
    m.ID, m.Test, m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3,
    e.E_Col1, e.E_Col2, e.E_Col3,
    s.First, s.Last
FROM M_Table AS m
INNER JOIN E_Table AS e ON (m.Test = r.Test)
JOIN S_Table AS s ON (m.ID = s.ID AND e.ID = s.ID)
WHERE m.Test LIKE '%2013%';
```

This gives me:

[image: Results that I am getting from my JOIN]

Now, I understand that I am joining on the Test column, which means that I should only be getting tests that they both share, but I am not sure how to join it such that I get the results that I want. Moreover, I know I am only taking the test column from the math table, but I don't want two test columns.

I am sure there is a way to do this, I am just not sure how. If I need to clarify my question, please let me know.

Comment: just change both joins to left joins

Comment: If I do that, it gives me a bunch of NULLS in the in Name Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to bring records from both ends of the relationship between the Math table and the English table. Basically, `FULL OUTER JOIN` returns all records from both tables, combining them when the join conditions do match, else filling the columns of the missing relation to `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(m.ID, e.ID) id, COALESCE(m.Test, e.Test) Test, 
    m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3, 
    e.E_Col1, e.E_Col2, e.E_Col3, 
    s.First, s.Last
FROM M_Table AS m
FULL OUTER JOIN E_Table AS e ON m.Test = e.Test AND e.ID = e.ID
INNER JOIN S_Table AS s ON COALESCE(m.ID, e.ID) =  s.ID
WHERE COALESCE(m.Test, e.Test) LIKE '%2013%';
```

Tip: merging together tables Math and English would probably simplify your database design. What is the benefit of splitting the information over two tables that have the same structure, and how will it scale when more subjects come into play? You could just use a unique table, with an additional column to store the name of the subject (Math, English, ...).

Comment: Though the structure is similar, the only column they have in common are the Test and ID columns, otherwise, the English and Math records are unique to that test. Essentially, if I merged them, then 90% of the cells would be NULL. Is that a sensible reason? My DB design experience isn't exactly huge.

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch: I understand. In this case you are probably better off with two separated tables. That was just a *tip* based on the sample data you provided.

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch: did you get a chance to test the above `FULL OUTER JOIN` query?

Comment: When I do it, it says "No Column Name" over the ID and Test columns. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch: please have a look at the current version of the query in the answer. I added column heads for `ID` and `Test`. Apart from the column headers, are you getting the correct data in the resultset?

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of all the id and tests -- you can get that like this

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Test FROM Math_Table as M
UNION
SELECT e.ID, e.Test FROM English_Table as E
```

Run that and understand the output

Then you take that and join it to the names and left join it to the tests like this

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Test, m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3, e.E_Col1, e.E_Col2, e.E_Col3, s.First, s.Last
FROM (
  SELECT m.ID, m.Test FROM Math_Table as M
  UNION
  SELECT e.ID, e.Test FROM English_Table as E
) as base
JOIN S_Table as S ON Base.ID = S.ID
LEFT JOIN M_Table AS m ON m.ID = base.ID AND m.Test = base.Test
LEFT JOIN E_Table AS e ON e.ID = base.ID AND e.Test = base.Test 
WHERE base.Test LIKE '%2013%'
```

Comment: Do you know why I am getting some NULLs in the ID and Test columns?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch -- that is how sql works with left joins.  just translate nulls to empty strings if you want.